# POST request from within Android app returns a Connection refused, but it works form the browser

Tags: java, android, networking, post, android-asynctask

From within my Android app I'm trying to make a POST request to an API which I built using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). The API works using the following message from the [Postman REST-Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm):

```
POST /api/message/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.10:5000
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"text": "This is a message"}
```

This works correctly and returns `{"testkey": "testmessage"}` just as expected. I now make a call from within my Android app using the following AsyncTask:

```
private class SendMessageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... messages) {

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.10/api/message/1");
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            json.put("text", messages);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        try {
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        try {
            client.execute(post);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I simply call this using `new SendMessageTask().execute(message.text);`.
This however, gives an error saying `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.0.10:5000 refused`.

When I simply type in the same url in the browser of my phone I get the expected response (I know that's a GET, but I don't even check for GET or POST on the API side yet).

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: is your base_url does fine...

Comment: Yes. In fact, in the original code I had it as a full string, I just replaced it here with the full string as well.

Comment: why you use 10.0.0.10 ??

Comment: @RanjitPati - 10.0.0.10 is my ip address on the local network, on which I'm also with my phone. This is proven by the fact that I can get into it from the phone browser. I didn't choose 10.0.0.10, It's just assigned to me by the network. I addeed it as a full string in the code now as well.

Comment: i think you have to use your local Ip address for testing with your device.i don't think 10.0.0.10 is an Ip...check your cmd..

Comment: The ip address is my correct local ip address on our network. I'm 100% sure of that, since I can also put that URI into my phones browser, which gets me the result of the API I expect. So please don't focus on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` add this tag into `AndroidManifest.xml` of your Android project.

Comment: beat me to it by 2 seconds :)

Comment: i have this same problem but this answer doesnt help.. any ideas?